# Преобразование строки в Python выражение (программа падает при слишком больших числах)

Tags: python

Есть пользователь который вводит выражение типа `"100 + 100 / 10"`, которое необходимо привести в некое число преобразовав в питоновское выражение.

Для парсинга использую [py_expression_eval](https://pypi.org/project/py-expression-eval/):

```py
from py_expression_eval import Parser

parser = Parser()
parser.parse("100 + 100 / 10").evaluate({})
```

Пишу команду `!math` для Discord бота на [hikari](https://pypi.org/project/hikari/) & [hikari-lightbulb](https://pypi.org/project/hikari-lightbulb/).

Проблема в том, что при вводе выражения типа `100000000000000000 ^ 100000000000000000` бот ложится не выбрасывая абсолютно никаких ошибок.

Пробовал ещё [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr), но тоже самое.

С чем может быть связано? Как обрабатывать такие "краш-числа"?

**UPD:**
Да не нужно мне эти числа вычислять! Мне нужно защитить программу от ввода пользователя.

Comment: Может быть, если вы не хотите свой парсер писать, тогда просить библиотеку отдать полученное выражение вам, а не считать его и вычислять самому средствами питона? Он то уж точно `MemoryError` выкинет, ну и по-хорошему бы эти библиотеки в отдельности от бота потестить как себя ведут на таких входных данных, вообще сомнительно, что они просто "ложатся без ошибок"

Comment: `Numexpr` на выражении `100000000000000000 ^ 100000000000000000` не падает, тем более, что это же просто "исключающее или", тут нет каких-то бешеных вычислений. Или вы имели в виду возведение в степень? А зачем вам такие числа возводить в степень? Там в любом случае упрётся всё в точность и размер чисел.

Comment: Это степень, а такие числа мне и не нужны, но они могут быть введены пользователем.

Comment: Такую степень сам питон не может нормально "переварить". Есть ситуации, которые могут озадачить собственно сам интерпретатор питона. И тут мало что можно сделать. Только отлавливать как-то то, что он "подвис".

Comment: Я вот проверил сейчас в `Google Colab`, уже даже `1_000_000 ** 1_000_000` считается порядка 4 секунды и даёт число из `6000001` цифры, а следующий подсчёт `10_000_000 ** 10_000_000` я пока не дождался. С вашими же цифрами, наверное, будет считаться бесконечно и даст числовую последовательность какой-то бешеной длины. Что с ней будет делать ваш пользователь, даже если он её получит каким-то чудом?

Comment: Реалистичный сценарий - делать отдельный поток для вычисления, ждать какое-то время и потом если не дождались результата убивать поток и сообщать пользователю, что он ввёл слишком сложное вычисление, пусть попробует чего попроще.

Comment: Что-то интересное. Попробую.

Comment: Менее реалистичный сценарий - запускать вычисления в отдельном процессе на который наложены ограничения по потребляемой памяти и процессорному времени. Так работают проверяющие машины на всяких олимпиадных сайтах.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну там уже докер контейнеры какие-нибудь запускаются )

Comment: [Код](https://github.com/axiacore/py-expression-eval/blob/master/py_expression_eval/__init__.py) не сложный. Его можно доработать: в функцию `evaluate` добавить ограничения на исходные числа. Если ограничения нарушены, бросать исключение. Работа займёт несколько часов.

Comment: От безысходности забрасывал затею на некоторое время. И да, если в интерактивном режиме проделать данную операцию, интепретатор виснет и начинает как не в себя сжирать CPU. Возможно как-то доработаю логику самого парсера. Потоки тоже не помогли.

Answer (score 3):

Как я уже написал в комментариях, вычисление таких степеней очень затратно и интерпретатор питона на них просто подвисает. Вот вам пример, что с этим можно сделать с помощью таймаут-декоратора, который нужно предварительно установить (их на самом деле много разных написано, я выбрал первый попавшийся в поиске):

```
pip install timeout-decorator
```

Ну и библиотеку парсинга выражений заодно напишу как ставить для полной воспроизводимости кода:

```
pip install py_expression_eval
```

Этим кодом я покажу, какое время считаются разные степени и какой длины получаются числа в результате этих вычислений, ну и как использовать декоратор таймаута:

```py
import sys
import math
import time
import timeout_decorator
from py_expression_eval import Parser

# без увеличения этого значения вычисление выражений падает
sys.set_int_max_str_digits(1_000_000_000)

@timeout_decorator.timeout(5)
def mycalc(n):
    parser = Parser()
    return parser.parse(n).evaluate({})

def mytest():
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            t1 = time.perf_counter()
            n = 10 ** i
            s = f"{n} ^ {n}"
            x = mycalc(s)
            t2 = time.perf_counter()
            t = t2-t1
            l = 1 + int(math.log10(x))
            print(f'Шаг: {i}, Вычисление: {s:^20}, Время: {t:.6f}, Получено цифр: {l}', flush=True)
    except TimeoutError:
        print(f'Шаг: {i}, Вычисление: {s:^20}, Превышено допустимое время!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mytest()
```

Результат работы кода:

```
Шаг: 0, Вычисление:        1 ^ 1        , Время: 0.007594, Получено цифр: 1
Шаг: 1, Вычисление:       10 ^ 10       , Время: 0.000222, Получено цифр: 11
Шаг: 2, Вычисление:      100 ^ 100      , Время: 0.000238, Получено цифр: 201
Шаг: 3, Вычисление:     1000 ^ 1000     , Время: 0.000255, Получено цифр: 3001
Шаг: 4, Вычисление:    10000 ^ 10000    , Время: 0.003241, Получено цифр: 40001
Шаг: 5, Вычисление:   100000 ^ 100000   , Время: 0.095435, Получено цифр: 500001
Шаг: 6, Вычисление:  1000000 ^ 1000000  , Время: 4.649145, Получено цифр: 6000001
Шаг: 7, Вычисление: 10000000 ^ 10000000 , Превышено допустимое время!
```

Количество цифр я считаю не через `len(str(x))`, а через десятичный логарифм, потому что этот подсчёт без установки параметра `int_max_str_digits` вообще падает, а если его поставить побольше, как у меня и сделано (для работы библиотеки парсинга выражений), то уже это вычисление начинает работать очень долго, поэтому пришлось через логарифм, но логарифм всё-равно даёт тот же результат, только моментально, я проверял на небольших значениях переменной цикла, да и просто по логике.

Comment: Отличное решение!

Comment: @Павел Я, правда, полностью проигнорировал собственно тему парсинга при этом )  Надо будет наверстать...

Comment: Думаю, что всё нормально, тут гораздо важнее момент с вылетом, парсинг можно как угодно сделать)

Comment: @Павел Переделал таки под парсинг, который использует автор вопроса )

Comment: При запуске вашего кода у меня сразу выводится `Шаг: 0, Вычисление:        1 ^ 1        , Превышено допустимое время!`.  Даже на таймауте в минуту.

Comment: @DWolf_19 А вот зря я все подряд эксепшены ловлю, так делать не следует. Поменял код. С ним у вас какой-то другой эксепшен должен выпасть, думаю, покажите, что там выйдет. И ещё напишите, какая у вас версия питона на всякий.

Comment: Питон я держу самый последний.

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGALRM'. Did you mean: 'SIGABRT'?` - ошибка возникает в самой библиотеке при запуске

Comment: @DWolf_19 А, понятно, значит данная библиотека в вашей ОС не работает (  Ну, поищите ещё варианты, я этих timeout decorator несколько штук находил. В крайнем случае можно и свой написать.

Answer (score 3):

Доставьте память в компьютер, чтобы не было свопа.

Сколько памяти потребуется чтобы сохранить *100000000000000000<sup>100000000000000000</sup>* ?

Питон хранит длинные целые в виде цепочек из 30-битных слов. Каждое слово занимает 4 байта. Число *n* в таком представлении занимает *4·log<sub>2<sup>30</sup></sub>(n)* байт. Вычислим место :

*4·log<sub>2<sup>30</sup></sub>(100000000000000000<sup>100000000000000000</sup>) =*

*= 4·ln(100000000000000000<sup>100000000000000000</sup>) / ln(2<sup>30</sup>) =*

*= 4·100000000000000000·ln(100000000000000000) / ln(2<sup>30</sup>) ≈*

*≈ 4·10<sup>17</sup>·39.14 / 20.79 байт ≈ 7.53·10<sup>17</sup> байт = 753 петабайт*

Архитектуру компьютера менять не надо, 64 разрядов достаточно чтобы адресовать такое количество памяти (*2<sup>64</sup> ≈ 1.64·10<sup>19</sup> > 7.53·10<sup>17</sup>*). Память придётся докупить. При текущих ценах на память - 21 миллиард рублей за 5.5 миллионов планок по 128 гигабайт каждая.

Comment: Обновил вопрос (мне нужно защитить программу от ввода пользователя, мне не нужно это вычислять). Но респект за креативность.

Comment: Сделайте защиту по времени вычисления. Защитится от исчерпания памяти сложнее, но по защита по времени обработает 99% вводов, а может и все 100% (зависит от того какие выражения разрешены).